# How to get mails from microsoft outlook graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have a requirement where I have to connect with Microsoft Outlook and get all emails for all user in that tenant (domain).

I am able to get data for one user using 
`/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages` but I want retrieve mails for all users.

We have around 1000 users but I want to get mails from one call. I don't want to make user specific calls 1000 times.

I have gone through docs but didn't found anything.

Comment: I truly dont think thats possible. 
Graph API doesnt allow this kind of operation (either a specific user by principle name \ id) or yours by "me"

Comment: if there are some users say 20 - 50 than its fine but for getting mails for 1000 user will cause performance degradation also in future users may increase. Any thought?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible, nor would it be practical, to "get mails from one call". You need to retrieve [messages](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages) by mailbox using the user name:

```
GET /v1.0/users/{user-id}/messages
```